# How to initialize UITableView before viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have to initialize my `UITableView` instance within `viewDidLoad`, such as:

```
tableView1 = UITableView(frame: frame)
```

However, when I tried to access the view controller that includes the `tableView1`, the `UITableViewDataSource`'s `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` is called before the `viewDidLoad` method, and within the `numberOfRowsInSection:`, I want to refer to the `tableView1` like `if tableView == tableView1`.

However, then how can I initialize the `tableView1` before calling `viewDidLoad`? If I tried to initialize it within `viewDidLoad` but still refer to it from within `numberOfRowsInSection:`, then it causes the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` because it is not initialized yet and hence its value is `nil`.

I think if I use storyboard and `@IBOutlet`, I don't have the problem. But now I use them all from my code, so I'm not sure how I can cope with the issue.

#### UPDATE

If this cannot be done as posted by @coolcracker, then how can I port this Objective-C code?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo;
if (tableView == _tableView1) {
    sectionInfo = _frc1.sections[section];
} else if (tableView == _tableView2) {
    sectionInfo = _frc2.sections[section];
}

return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
}
```

Comment: simply you can not do this

Comment: You haven't created the tableView1, so the delegate was sent by tableView2.

Comment: Maybe what you want is something like `if (_tableView1 != nil && tableView == _tableView1) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use Storyboard at all, just declare and initialise your tableview as follows

```
@interface ApplicationsPageGroups : UIViewController
{
  UITableView* tableView1; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] init];
   tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 95, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-230);
   tableView1.delegate = self;
   tableView1.dataSource = self;
   tableView1.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
   [self.view addSubview:tableView1];
   [self getTableData];
 }
 -(void) getTableData
{
   // after you get some array of data to fill the tableview
   [tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

Now override all the UITableView delegate and dataSource methods.

Comment: Then what should I return in `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: I already mentioned call reloadData "after you get some array of data to fill the tableview"...then return that array size as numberOfRowsInSection or else return 0.

Answer (score 0):

simply add

```
[tableView1 reloadData];
```

which call your DataSource methods call again

Answer (score 0):

You could override the view controller initWithFrame or initWithNibOrNil method and initialize the tableViews there.

Also, have you tried initializing the table views BEFORE calling the [super viewDidLoad] method? I have not checked, but it may be possible that the superclass controller is calling the reload method before your initializers, depending on your class hierarchy.